# Displaying an image from resources in Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I'm trying to display a simple png image using **Java Swing**. The image is stored inside the project folder, more precisely in: `~/Workspace/MyProject/res/logo.png`.

Inside a class named `FirstAccess.java` that extends `JFrame` i therefore declared:

```
final BufferedImage myLogo = ImageIO.read(new File("../res/logo.png"));
final JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myLogo));
// [...]
```

But this generates the following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>
> at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
>
> [...]
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What's the problem? Am I using the wrong path? Is there maybe some access privileges issue?

**Note:** `FirstAccess.java` is located exactly in `~/Workspace/MyProject/src/main/`

**Note2**: I also tried with the path `"~/Workspace/MyProject/res/logo.png"` inside `new File()`... but still gives the same problem.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  **An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.**  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

For resources, use `getClass().getResource(String)` instead.
In your case:

`final BufferedImage myLogo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../res/logo.png"));`



( *or `final BufferedImage myLogo = ImageIO.read(FirstAccess.class.getResource("../res/logo.png"));` for static context*)